# Clearing variable via link PHP/Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I call a variable from a component to get a users location:

JRequest::getInt('CS_SESSION_LOCATIONID', null, 'COOKIE');

Only trouble is that in some case's I want to reset the value from a link. Any body got any idea how to clear CS_SESSION_LOCATIONID ?

I've tried: clear and various other methods, but cant seem to find a way. I'm basically looking to create a link which will re-direct to the index page & re-set the users selected location to nothing.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to unset($variable) the variable?